# Text horizontally overflowing into next inline div

Tags: css

Is it possible to make text overflow horizontally into (and over) the next div when displaying many divs inline?

Example:

html:

> ```
> <div class="div1">I want the text to overflow into the red box</div>
> <div class="div2"></div>
> ```

css:

```
  div{
      float:left;
      display:inline;
      width: 200px;
      height: 18px; }

  .div1{
      background-color: grey;  }

  .div2{
       background-color: red; }
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lars95/H7KvG/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, add this

```
.div1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

Should you want to give div2 a position relative as well, make sure the z-index of div1 is higher then the z-index of div2.

<kbd>[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7KvG/7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` and `white-space: nowrap;`to your `div1`. Specify that the text in paragraphs will never wrap:

```
.div1{
        background-color: grey; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of things to be noted here

1. `white-space: nowrap;` - this is used when you want a paragraphs never to wrap
2. put your content inside `<p>` . you will have a lot more control over everything when you do it like this
3. `overflow visible` - since your `<p>` is bigger then the container `<div>` then you need allow the container to display whats inside
4. `position relative + z-index` . you need this so that the first container is on top of the second . allowing the content inside to be displayed
5. you dont need `display: inline` . floated elements are `block`

so your code will become:

```
<div class="div1">
    <p>I want the text to overflow into the red box</p>
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
div{
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 18px;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.div1{
    background-color: grey; 
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.div2{
     background-color: red;
}
```

updated fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/H7KvG/8/